Get device information from Zebra LS2208 Scanner
I have a C# application that opens a SerialPort to receive scan data from a Zebra LS2208 Barcode Scanner. The device is connected via USB and is using Windows 10 CDC setup to be Serial via USB.
The scanning works great. What I am trying to do is setup the class to effectively "search" or "Discover" the device. To do that I need a command I can send to the port to verify the device is connected. I am having trouble finding a command that I could send that will generate any return bytes from the scanner.
For example
_port = new SerialPort(....)
_port.Open()
// Tells the device to Beep (I think)
_port.Write(new byte[]{7}, 0, 1) 
if(_port.BytesToRead > 0) ....

There are never bytes to read, but the scanner does beep (a good beep)
I was hoping to find something that wasn't specific to Zebra, that way possibly any scanner would would provided is configuration matched expected. At this point I would be happy for a zebra specific command. A 'version' command would be even better as I would love to report that information to the application using the device.
Note I am not using HID as I have a windows service that needs to receive the scan, decode it, then pass that value onto another service

Did you read the documentation and watch the videos?

Have you tried using the Zebra Scanner SDK
